# Swisscom Application Cloud: What mail service to use?

Tags: swisscomdev

We have a Node.js application on the internal application cloud. What mailing service is recommended? I saw that RabbitMQ is available but it doesn't support smtp natively.

In case it makes a difference: We don't need to access received mails - we only need to send mails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RabbitMQ is a message broker, has no feature to send SMTP mails. Messaging != mailing.

from Wikipedia:

> RabbitMQ is an open source message broker software (sometimes called
>   message-oriented middleware) that originally implemented the Advanced
>   Message Queuing Protocol (AMQP) and has since been extended with a
>   plug-in architecture to support Streaming Text Oriented Messaging
>   Protocol (STOMP), MQTT, and other protocols

Swisscom internals can use this mail server / operated by classic teams.

- appmail.swisscom.com
- port 25
- no authentication
- no SSL

You need to whitelist your sender address (needs to be official and valid Swisscom exchange mailbox) and the IP address. You can see your IP address when you `cf ssh` into app container and do `curl ifconfig.co`.

Contact for white list operations is *CoC.Messaging* and/or *Support.SMMS*.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Won't the IP change when re-deploying the app?

Comment: Another question... how can I develop/test locally?